# Recursive Type Definition for a Matrix

Tags: javascript, typescript, matrix, typescript-typings

I have been working on trying to make a recursive type definition for a matrix, but I don't really understand how to write one from reading PRs.  My idea is that the `MatrixLiteral` type definition should accept the following values:

```
const test1D: MatrixLiteral = [0, 2, 1];

const test2D: MatrixLiteral = [
  [3, 14, 2],
  [6, 2, 1],
];

const test3D: MatrixLiteral = [
  [
    [3, 14, 2],
    [6, 2, 1],
  ],
  [
    [3, 14, 2],
    [6, 2, 1],
  ],
];
```

But I just can't get any types to work for it.  Also, note that I only want there to be `number` types within the arrays.  Thank you for your time!

Another note: the rank of the matrix will always be greater than 0. (`rank > 0`)

Comment: Ok, I got to `type MatrixLiteral = [...(number | MatrixLiteral)[]];` but is there a way that I can make sure that the elements of all of the arrays are either a type of `number` or `number[]`?

Comment: You can simplify that type to `type MatrixLiteral = (number | MatrixLiteral)[]`. That should do what you want; what values does it permit that you don't think it should?

Comment: @DylanSp I was hoping that there was a way to make sure that typescript enforces that there must be numbers within all of the last children of the given `MatrixLiteral`.

Comment: @DylanSp Also I needed to have it my way because the rank must be greater than 0. (I don't want it to be set to just `1` or any other number)

Comment: So you want to rule out empty arrays at the bottom level, is that what you're asking? The type provided won't allow strings/booleans/etc.

Comment: I want it to know that the bottom-most array is a number so I don't have to do type checks to make sure they are numbers.

Comment: That's done by `type MatrixLiteral = (number | MatrixLiteral)[]`; as I said, that doesn't permit any other type at the bottom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force arrays to not be empty with the following

```
type MatrixLiteral =
    | [number, ...number[]]
    | [MatrixLiteral, ...MatrixLiteral[]]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsATgSwB4BlnAouAbKAXgCgoyoAfKAbQDsBXAWwCMcAaKAOm4ZZ2oC6A0uSrV4SNJmy48HbpwkoMWHPkHDiAYwD2tAM7Ao2QwC5YCZdLUFCNEWWoBGDgCYOAZgFsHNF1HcoLx9hXQMjCEYwUABBRFwQfThECAAhOAATcyUpVVkie3Iab19nN09hUL1DKEY0CAy4hP04tMzsy1yZfALqUv9A6g8OABYhEKA)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple recursive type: `type MatrixLiteral = number[] | MatrixLiteral[];`.

Comment: This will allow things like `[1,[2,[3,[4,[5]]]]]` which may or may not be desirable.  I'm not sure what kind of constraints the OP really wants to enforce here.

Comment: @jcalz True; I made it more restrictive in an edit, which rules out that example, but still doesn't enforce length requirements. Not sure that you could prevent, say, `[[1, 2], [3]]` in TS's type system.